# Erro ao instalar plugin OneSignal na plataforma iOS usando IONIC FRAMEWORK

Tags: ionic, ios, apache-cordova

Estou desenvolvendo um app usando ionic framework, porém ao adicionar o plugin do OneSignal na plataforma iOS estou tendo alguns erros:

> "Failed to install 'onesignal-cordova-plugin': undefined (node:3302)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection
>   (rejection id: 1): Version should contain only numbers and dots"

Já efetuei alguns comandos como:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
prod repo update
```

Mas não obtive êxito.

Alguém teria alguma dica do que devo fazer para poder instalar o OneSignal?

Answer (score 2):

Testa fazer esses procedimentos

```
cordova platform remove ios
cordova platform remove onesignal-cordova-plugin
sudo gem install cocoapods
pod repo update
pod setup (caso precise sincronizar o repositório CocoaPods)
cordova plugin add onesignal-cordova-plugin --save
cordova platform add ios
```